# Website not resizing to mobile but desktop and tablet are ok

Tags: css, mobile, resize

Website not resizing to mobile

Desktop and tablet are ok, but mobile is not resizing. Even the picture is wrong on mobile. This is what I have tried and have on code at the moment.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SiteName</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
```

And

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

/* Desktop */
@import url("desktop.css");
/* Tablet */
@import url("tablet.css") only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px);
/* Phone */
@import url("phone.css") only screen and (max-width:320px);
```

Feel free to ask for more details. I am a beginner and still learning.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your mobile phone narrower then 320px? Usually 320px is the width of really small phones.

Comment: I use 768px max width for mobile devices

Comment: https://blogs.perficient.com/2014/12/24/css-pixel-ratio-or-how-big-is-my-phone/ here you find a nice table of physical pixels sizes and logical(css) sizes. If you want to target phones use max-width768px

Comment: Thank you @TheMrkt! I tried to change the dimensions but didn't help.